# GNU make use file as target in SUFFIXES

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autoconf, automake

Makefile is using

```
.SUFFIXES: .ext1

.ext1:
      echo bla bla
```

I have a configuration file path/to/abc.ext1 so **make path/to/abc** works fine.

I want **make path/to/abc.ext1** to work as well. It would be great if I can reuse existing .ext1 target.

Comment: When you do "make abc.ext1", what do you want Make to do? Do you want it to build `abc.ext1`? Or `path/to/abc.ext1`?

Comment: path/to/abc.ext1 already exists and I don't want to build it. I want echo bla bla to get printed. Normally running make abc prints echo bla bla.

Comment: We can't give you a useful answer if you don't put in the effort to pose the question clearly. *What command are you using to invoke Make?*

Comment: Let me try to improve it. I am using "make path/to/abc.ext1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to summarize what I have understood:

1. The file `path/to/abc.ext1` already exists.
2. You already have `make path/to/abc` echoing `bla bla` without creating the file `path/to/abc`.
3. You woud like `make path/to/abc.ext1` to behave like `make path/to/abc`.  In your current setup it does not work because `path/to/abc.ext1` already exists, so `make` has no reason to trigger a rule to "rebuild" it.

In your case, you are not building any of the files `abc` or `abc.ext1`, so you should really tell `make` that these are phony targets.  (I assume you want `make abc` to work even if `abc` already exist and is newer than `abc.ext1`, right?)

For a single file, you could have something like:

```
.PHONY: path/to/abc.ext1 path/to/abc
path/to/abc.ext1 path/to/abc:
        @echo bla bla
```

This way, `make path/to/abc.ext1` or `make path/to/abc` will always run `echo bla bla` regardless of the existence of `path/to/abc.ext1` or `path/to/abc` (`make` will never check their existence).

Unfortunately, `.PHONY` require an explicit list of targets.  With GNU make you could compute that list of targets with `$(wildcard...)` or if you need to recurse into subdirectories, with `$(shell find...)`.  For instance:

```
EXT1_FILES = $(shell find -type f -name '*.ext1' -print)
PHONY_TARGETS = $(EXT1_FILES) $(EXT1_FILES:.ext1=)

.PHONY: $(PHONY_TARGETS)
$(PHONY_TARGETS):
        @echo bla bla
```

The `$(EXT1_FILES:.ext1=)` just strips all `.ext1` extensions from the filenames in `$(EXT1_FILES)`.

If you have a very large tree, you will suffer from the `$(shell find...)` invocation: it is runs every time your `Makefile` is loaded by `make`.  If it's too slow, you could replace it by the explicit list of filename (maybe generated automatically).

Your question gives zero context, so it's hard to suggest more useful alternatives.  It still feels like you are trying to abuse `make`.  When you state something like "`make foo.ext1` should run some commands even if `foo.ext1` exists", that's fishy.  Can't you write a simple shell script that takes one argument, and does `echo bla bla` whenever `$1` or `$1.ext1` exist?  It would probably be a lot easier than trying to work around `make`'s semantics.

Comment: This does solve the problem mentioned in question. I have to work around make semantics because echo "bla bla" is lot more complicated and had recursive calls back to target. So, doing it using make semantics will need overhaul of build system. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a rule for `abc.ext1`, then running `make abc.ext1` will work.  Suffix rules are only searched if there is no explicit rule available.

If that doesn't work for your situation please explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: I tried this earlier and it wasn't working because conf file is inside a folder. Looks like / doesn't work in target, suggestion ?

Comment: If I use %.ext1: as my target it doesn't work. It says: make 'path/to/abc.ext1' update to date.

Comment: You need to edit your question to add in these details.  Things like the fact that the file is in a different directory, etc. are absolutely critical to providing answers.  As it is your question contains nowhere near enough information for us to answer it.  You should show your makefile, cut/paste the command you type now and the output, then show the command you want to type and exactly what you want to happen when you type it.

Comment: I think as you pointed out the problem is full path. make path/to/abc.ext1 doesn't match %.ext1

Answer (score 0):

MadScientist's answer seems correct, but I think there's a miscommunication here.

If you have this rule:

```
%.ext1:
    echo bla bla
```

and you `make abc.ext1`, what happens?